# Is it possible to detect if the google spreadsheet was edited manually or via google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have google spreadsheets with scripts embedded on it to generate data automatically from a remote server. I just want to know if it is possible to know if the modification on a certain sheet was done via google script or was edited manually in the edit history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new user in your Google Apps domain that the script is 'run as'. That way you'll know whether it was the script or a user that made the edits